# Calling 'next()' from promises in a middleware causes 'next shouldn't be called more than once'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, restify

Recently I changed my code from Express to Restify. I'm honestly not sure if it used to happen before, but I guess it did.

Basically in my middleware I call a promisified method and when it resolves I call `next` and do other stuff in the next middleware. When it is rejected I also want to call `next` with no errors in some cases. Otherwise it must call the error middleware passing `err` to `next`.

```
somePromise()
.then(()=>{
    next();
})
.catch((err)=>{
    if(err.someatt) next();
    else next(err)
});
```

It works fine with the expected results of `somePromise`. The problem is that `next` is bound by the `then-catch` chain. And when an error is thrown in the next middleware it invokes the `catch` method and calls `next` again!

I found out that next has an attribute `called` and when I turn it to false before calling next again I get rid of the the errors. But of course it is an antipattern. And I'm having the same problem in a different middleware that I also used promises (calling `next` as expected and then calling it again in the `catch` statement).

Anyone else had a problem like that?

Comment: You can try/catch around your first call to `next()` so that exception doesn't propagate to your `.catch()` handler.  Or you can use both arguments to `.then()` so a rejection/exception in the first `.then()` callback doesn't go to that catch handler.

Comment: yes! i did it already. The problem is that I need to call the error middleware. I have to break it in parts so I can call it from the try/catch and from the middleware stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your chain to this:

```
somePromise().then(() => {
  next();
}, err => {
  // error occurred in somePromise()
  if(err.someatt) next();
  else next(err);
}).catch(err => {
  // error occurred in .then()'s next()
  // don't call next() again
});
```

The optional second argument of [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) acts as a `.catch()` callback, but is only invoked for errors thrown higher up in the chain, and is not invoked for errors thrown in the adjacent `.then()` callback.

A very helpful flowchart borrowed from [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1541563) demonstrates the difference between `.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` and `.then(onFulfilled).catch(onRejected)`:

[image: promise then]
[image: promise then-catch]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But if I can't call next again I can't really use my error middleware, right?!

Comment: @VictorFerreira if your middleware is throwing an error, then you have a bug that needs to be fixed. Either you're not catching a vexing / exogenous exception close enough to where it happens, or you're trying to catch a boneheaded exception that needs to be prevented from happening in the first place. See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) for explanation of the terminology.

Comment: Sure I understand that. But what is weird about this is that this middleware that is calling `next` suddenly became responsible for all uncaught errors in the application. If I was not using `then-catch` it wouldnt be caught by this middleware. And the error the application is getting is 'next cant be called more than once' or 'uncaught promise rejection' . Its not good, because it is silent or doesnt show clearly what the error really is

Comment: Then use my pattern, and any errors that show up in the `.catch()` callback at the end of the chain are indications of bugs that need to be fixed. Log their `stack` property and it will show you exactly where the error originates.

Comment: Yes! This is a prime example of why `.then(successHandler, errorHandler)` is pattern, not anti-pattern as it is often dubbed.